# JavaScript to Output Text Based on User's Current Time

Tags: javascript, string, text, time

I don't know JavaScript, but I am familiar with following directions. I know a little PHP.

I'm looking for a piece of JS that will output a particular string of text for my header, based on the user's current time.

For example:

```
12:00AM - 12:00PM - Good Morning!  
12:00PM - 6:00PM - Good Afternoon!  
6:00PM - 12:00AM - Good Evening!
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try following piece of Javascript code:

```
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()

if (curHr < 12) {
  console.log('good morning')
} else if (curHr < 18) {
  console.log('good afternoon')
} else {
  console.log('good evening')
}
```

Comment: This works for me. Of course I had to change console.log to document.write to get it to output to the page. I chose this because it is simplest and works for my needs, although some others' answers below may be more correct.

Comment: sir its not working for me properly because at evening in my clock time is 7O'clock but its return me 6 from currHr so tell me why get 6?

Comment: This is good but Derek's answer's design is more elegant and dynamic instead of hard coding 3-4 if cases

Answer (score 17):

```
var data = [
    [0, 4, "Good night"], 
    [5, 11, "Good morning"],          //Store messages in an array
    [12, 17, "Good afternoon"],
    [18, 24, "Good night"]
],
    hr = new Date().getHours();

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    if(hr >= data[i][0] && hr <= data[i][1]){
        console.log(data[i][2]);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/we8Ty/

Comment: It's 12:21 by my computer clock, yet it said good morning. Is it possible that it only truncates the hours so, perhaps the array should say 0, 11? I have no idea, merely suggesting.

Comment: @MikeMeldrem - I'm pretty sure it should be `[0,11]`... No idea why I put `[0,12]` before.

Answer (score 10):

This is just a small variation of the solution from Derek 朕會功夫 above.
I felt the array is cleaner than a bunch of `if` statements.
If you work the hours backwards, you don't need a start *AND* end hour.
Also, once you make a match, I added a `break;` to kick out early.

```
var data = [
    [22, 'Working late'],
    [18, 'Good evening'],
    [12, 'Good afternoon'],
    [5,  'Good morning'],
    [0,  'Whoa, early bird']
],
hr = new Date().getHours();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (hr >= data[i][0]) {
        console.log(data[i][1])
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread, i'm just sharing this 2 lines of code for anyone who needs simple solution :)

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
console.log("Good " + (hour<12 && "Morning" || hour<18 && "Afternoon" || "Evening"))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var time = new Date().getHours();
   ,greeting = 'Good '+ (time < 12 ? 'Morning' : 
                         time < 18 ? 'Afternoon' : 'Evening');
//=> new Date('2012/11/06 13:10') => 'Good Afternoon'
//=> new Date('2012/11/06 10:33') => 'Good Morning'
//=> new Date('2012/11/06 19:23') => 'Good Evening'
```

Or augment `Date`

```
Date.prototype.greeting = function(){ 
   var time = this.getHours();
   return 'Good '+ (time<12 ? 'Morning' : time<18 ? 'Afternoon' : 'Evening');
};
new Date('2012/11/06 19:23').greeting() //=> 'Good Evening'
```

**[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCC6a/)**

Answer (score 3):

```
const date = new Date();
const currentTime = date.getHours();

let greeting;

if (currentTime >= 0 && currentTime <= 12) {
  greeting = "Good Morning";
} else if (currentTime > 12 && currentTime <= 18) {
  greeting = "Good Afternoon";
} else {
  greeting = "Good Evening";
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>{greeting}</h1>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please explain your solution.

Answer (score 3):

This should help you:

```
const currentTime = new Date().getHours();
let greetingText = "";

if (currentTime < 12) {
  greetingText = "Good Morning"; 
} else if (currentTime < 18) {
  greetingText = "Good Afternoon"; 
} else {
  greetingText = "Good Evening"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this js code, This should work..

```
var dt = new Date().getHours();
if (dt >= 0 && dt <= 11){
 console.log('GM')
}else if (dt >= 12 && dt <= 17){
 console.log('Good Afternoon!')
}else {
 console.log('GE')
}
```

Comment: What if you have a lot of `time` and `text`? The code will be so messy.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but it should work:

```
function getText()
{
  var hour = new Date().getHours();
  var minute = new Date().getMinutes();
  if ( hour >= 0 && hour < 12 )
    return 'Good Morning!';
  else if ( hour == 12 && minute == 0 )
    return 'Good Morning!';
  else if ( hour == 12 && minute > 0 )
    return 'Good Afternoon!';
  else if ( hour == 6 && minute == 0 )
    return 'Good Afternoon!';
  else if ( hour == 6 && minute > 0 )
    return 'Good Evening!';
  else if ( hour > 12 && hour < 6 )
    return 'Good Afternoon!'; 
  else if ( hour > 6 && hour < 12 )
    return 'Good Evening';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myDate = new Date();
    var name = window.prompt("Please enter your name: ");

    if (myDate.getHours() < 12) {
        document.write("Good Morning " +name);
    }
    else if(myDate.getHours() >=12 && myDate.getHours() <=17){
        document.write("Good Afternoon " +name);
    }
    else if (myDate.getHours() > 17 && myDate.getHours() <=24) {
        document.write("Good Evening " +name);
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("Good Night");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With moment.js & ES6:

```
import moment from 'moment';

console.log(`${getGreetingTime(moment())} ${userFirstName}`);

getGreetingTime = (currentTime) => {
  if (!currentTime || !currentTime.isValid()) { return 'Hello'; }

  const splitAfternoon = 12; // 24hr time to split the afternoon
  const splitEvening = 17; // 24hr time to split the evening
  const currentHour = parseFloat(currentTime.format('HH'));

  if (currentHour >= splitAfternoon && currentHour <= splitEvening) {
    return 'Good afternoon';
  } else if (currentHour >= splitEvening) {
    return 'Good evening';
  }
  return 'Good morning';
}
```

Adapted from [James1x0's gist](https://gist.github.com/James1x0/8443042).

Comment: It should be `currentHour < splitEvening`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var today = new Date();
    var curHr = today.getHours();

    if (curHr < 12) {
        console.log('good morning')
    } else if (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 16) {
        console.log('good afternoon')
    } else {
        console.log('good evening')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var day=new Date();
var hr=day.getHours();
ReactDOM.render(
<div>
<h1>
{"Good"+ (hr< 12 ? "Morning": hr < 18 ? "Afternoon" :"Evening")}
</h1></div>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the other existing answers and upvoted answers that this question already has.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

const today = new Date().getHours();

let greeting;

if (today < 12) {
  greeting = "Good Morning"
} else if (today < 18) {
  greeting = "Good Afternoon"
} else {
  greeting = "Good Night"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the problem described in the question, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with ES6 and Moment.js

```
  import moment from 'moment';

  const getGreetingTime = () => {
    const splitMorning = 6;
    const splitAfternoon = 12;
    const splitEvening = 17;
    const splitNight = 20;
    const currentHour = parseFloat(moment().format('HH'));
    if (currentHour >= splitMorning && currentHour <= splitAfternoon) {
      return 'Good morning';
    } else if (currentHour >= splitAfternoon && currentHour <= splitEvening) {
      return 'Good afternoon';
    } else if (currentHour >= splitEvening && currentHour <= splitNight) {
      return 'Good evening';
    }
    return 'Good night';
  };

  const greeting = getGreetingTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (hour >= 0 && hour < 3){
                return 'Good Late Night!';
            }
            else if (hour >= 3 && hour < 12){
                return 'Good Morning!';
            }
            else if (hour == 12 && minute == 0){
                return 'Good Morning!';
            }
            else if (hour == 12 && minute > 0){
                return 'Good Afternoon!';
            }
            else if (hour == 6 && minute == 0){
                return 'Good Afternoon!';
            }
            else if (hour == 6 && minute > 0){
                return 'Good Evening!';
            }
            else if (hour > 12 && hour <= 15){
                return 'Good Noon!';
            }
            else if (hour > 15 && hour <= 6){
                return 'Good Afternoon!';
            }
            else if (hour > 6 && hour < 12){
                return 'Good Evening';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a pure TypeScript function:

```
type SayHelloProps = {
  morning: string;
  afternoon: string;
  evening: string;
};

const sayHello = ({
  morning,
  afternoon,
  evening
}: SayHelloProps): string => {
  const currentTime = new Date();
  const currentHour = currentTime.getHours();

  switch (true) {
    case currentHour < 12:
      return morning;
    case currentHour > 12 && currentHour < 17:
      return afternoon;
    default:
      return evening;
  }
};
```

Readable, easy to use.