# How to have Heading Change based on Time of Day

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript but I have been working with HTML for a while now. I am trying to make a new website for fun and I would like for the heading to change based on the time of day. For example, I would like to display Good Morning in the morning, Good Afternoon in the afternoon, and Good Evening in the evening based on the time of the user's computer. I believe I will have to use javascript. Is there any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Do you have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code that you've tried and we can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13245058/7584019

```js
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()

if (curHr < 12) {
  console.log('good morning')
} else if (curHr < 18) {
  console.log('good afternoon')
} else {
  console.log('good evening')
}
```